# Serving multiple deep learning models from cluster

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mxnet

I was thinking about how one should deploy multiple models for use. I am currently dealing with tensorflow. I was referring [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-tensorflow-models-to-production-using-tf-serving-4b4b78d41700) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-1-make-your-model-ready-for-serving-776a14ec3198) article.

But I am not able to find any article which targets need to serve several models distributed manner. **Q.1.** Does tensorflow serving serve models off from single machine? Is there any way to set up a cluster of machines running tensorflow serving? So that multiple machines serve same model somewhat working as master and slave or say load balance between them while serving different models.

**Q.2.** Does similar functionality exist for other deep learning frameworks, say keras, mxnet etc (not just restricting to tensorflow and serving models from different frameworks)?

Answer (score 0):

**A1**: Serving tensorflow models in a distributed fashion is made easy with Kubernetes, a container orchestration system, that takes much of the pain related to having distributed system away from you, including load balancing. Please check [serving kubernetes](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_kubernetes).

**A2**: Sure, check for instance [Prediction IO](https://predictionio.apache.org/). It's not deep learning specific, but can be used to deploy models made with e.g. Spark MLLib.